# Return data whose birthday is today

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to set a query that will pull all clients whose birthday is today. I'm using `phpmyadmin` `localhost` via `Unix socket`, birthday is set as `DATE`.

All I need returned is the `firstname (emp.emp_firstname as`first name`)` , `lastname (emp.emp_lastname as`last name`)` and `date of birth (emp_birthday as 'dob')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be like this:

```
SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND DAY(emp_birthday)=DAY(CURDATE())
```

or if you want to consider also leap years, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  emp_birthday +
    INTERVAL
      YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(emp_birthday) +
      (MONTH(emp_birthday)<MONTH(CURDATE())
       OR (MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND DAY(emp_birthday)<DAY(CURDATE())))
    YEAR = CURDATE()
```

If someone's date of birth is on 29th of February, and today is 28th of February and this year is not a leap year, my last query will consider his/her birthday as today.

My second query could be also simplified like this:

```
SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  (MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND DAY(emp_birthday)=DAY(CURDATE()))
  OR (DAY(LAST_DAY(emp_birthday))=29
      AND DAY(emp_birthday)=29
      AND DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))=28);
```

Comment: @user2381420 you're welcome, if you need to support leap years and you don't want to forget people that were born on 29th of February, pls have a look at my last query :)

Answer (score 5):

```
select emp_firstname as first_name, 
       emp_lastname as last_name, 
       emp_birthday as dob
from emp
where month(emp_birthday) = month(curdate())
and  day(emp_birthday) = day(curdate())
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/062ad/4)

Comment: Hi thanks I tried this but it returned an empty result and I know there are two birthdays today?

Comment: i think that emp_birthday is the date of birth so it won't match curdate()

Answer (score 1):

```
select emp_firstname as first_name, 
       emp_lastname as last_name, 
       emp_birthday as dob
from emp
where DATE_FORMAT(emp_birthday,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a problem with date matching. Curdate() returns a midnight timestamp, but your dates of birth might not themselves be midnight timestamps for reasons hard to guess. Try this:

```
 SELECT emp_firstname AS first name, 
        emp_lastname  AS last name, 
        emp_birthday  AS dob
   FROM emp
  WHERE emp_birthday >= curdate()
    AND emp_birthday <  curdate() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but why not just

```
SELECT 
    emp_firstname AS first_name, 
    emp_lastname AS last_name, 
    emp_birthday AS dob
FROM rmp
WHERE DATE(emp_birthday) = CURDATE();
```

?